# Why wrapping awaitable async method into Task.Run improves the performance at least twice?

Tags: c#, async-await, task-parallel-library, httplistener

I have a simple implementation of HTTP Server. The code is shown below. It was tested on the server machine with 32cores. If I wrap the processContext method into Task.Run call, then the performance doubles (at least). Considering that this gave me a performance gain in this particular case, I am confused now: having some method returning a Task, which I don't wish to wait for, what strategy should I follow? Should I call it directly or should I wrap inside Task.Run?

```
class Program
{
    private static ConcurrentBag<DateTime> _trails = new ConcurrentBag<DateTime>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Is server GC: {(GCSettings.IsServerGC ? "true" : "false")}");

        string prefix = args[0];

        CancellationTokenSource cancellationSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

        HttpListener httpListener = new HttpListener();

        httpListener.Prefixes.Add(prefix);

        httpListener.Start();

        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (!cancellationSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                HttpListenerContext context = null;

                try
                {
                    context = await httpListener.GetContextAsync();

                    if (cancellationSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)
                    {
                        context.Response.Abort();

                        break;
                    }
                }
                catch (ObjectDisposedException)
                {
                    return;
                }
                catch (HttpListenerException ex)
                {
                    if (cancellationSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested && ex.ErrorCode == 995)
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                    throw;
                }

                // Uncommenting below line and commenting the next one improves the performance at least twice
                // Task childProcessingTask = Task.Run(async () => await processContext(context));

                var dt = processContext(context);
            }
        });

        using (Timer t = new Timer(o => Console.Title = $"Async Server: {_trails.Count}", null, 0, 5000))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Running...");

            Console.ReadLine();

            cancellationSource.Cancel();

            Console.WriteLine("Stopped accepting new request. Waiting for pending requests...");

            Console.WriteLine("Stopped");

            httpListener.Close();
        }

        var gTrails = _trails.GroupBy(t => new DateTime(t.Year, t.Month, t.Day, t.Hour, t.Minute, 0))
            .Select(g => new { MinuteDt = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
            .OrderBy(x => x.MinuteDt).ToList();

        gTrails.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"{x.MinuteDt:HH:mm}\t{x.Count}"));

        if (gTrails.Count > 2)
        {
            decimal avg = gTrails.Take(gTrails.Count - 1).Skip(1).Average(g => (decimal)g.Count);
            Console.WriteLine($"Average: {avg:0.00}/min, {avg / 60.0m:00.0}/sec");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static async Task processContext(HttpListenerContext context)
    {
        DateTime requestDt = DateTime.Now;
        Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        string requestId = context.Request.QueryString["requestId"];

        byte[] requestIdBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestId);

        context.Response.ContentLength64 = requestIdBytes.Length;

        await context.Response.OutputStream.WriteAsync(requestIdBytes, 0, requestIdBytes.Length);

        try
        {
            context.Response.Close();
        }
        catch { }

        _trails.Add(requestDt);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is only a guess as I'm still learning async/await but could it be because calling processContext like that is actually acting synchronously, while wrapping it in a task and not awaiting that task causes it to continue execution immediately?

Comment: @Phaeze, actually the method should partially be executed synchronously until the first await is reached and this is when I expect the asynchronicity to start. The problem is that per my understanding most of the awaitable methods are implemented this way. But how to call them for the best performance?

Comment: @Rauf: What exactly do you mean by "performance doubles"? I see a stopwatch but it's never read. Are you referring to how quickly it can accept connections?

Comment: @Stephen Cleary, as you can see from the code I'm accumulating all request time stamps and at the end calculate the average requests processed per second.

Answer (score 2):

> Why wrapping awaitable async method into Task.Run improves the performance at least twice?

Many async methods have a synchronous part, that’s running synchronously on the caller’s thread.
In case of your `processContext` method, the code of that method from the start to the first await is running on the caller’s thread.

**If you don’t use `Task.Run`**, after the connection’s accepted, your software first runs the synchronous portion of processContext method. It calls await, the task’s context goes to the heap, the thread’s free and resumes another iteration of `while (!cancellationSource.Token.IsCancellationRequested)` loop.
Soon the task’s finished and the scheduler wants to resume it.

But it can’t resume it on the same thread where it started, ‘coz that thread is likely busy listening for new connections and starting another child tasks.

You have many cores, there’s very good change the task will resume on another core. If it happens on another core of the same CPU, the core will have to wait for data (like local variables, HttpListenerContext instance variables, etc.) from L3 cache, because L1 and L2 caches are per core. If it happens on another CPU, the core will have to wait for the system RAM, which is even slower.

**If you use `Task.Run`**, the thread that was running that endless `while(!IsCancellationRequested)` loop stays doing that, and immediately continues to another iteration of that loop, all data already on the cache of that core.

The `processContext` method will start running on some other core from the very beginning. If you’re only sending a few bytes, that `await WriteAsync` is going to return very fast. The scheduler ain’t stupid. If you have 32 cores and not that many tasks, the scheduler will likely resume `processContext` task on the same core where it was started, with all your session-specific data already on the cache of that core.

> what strategy should I follow?

1. Test several techniques, pick whatever works better with your workload. Task.Run isn’t always faster, it’s just in your situation.
2. Or, understand how things work under the hood, you’ll them be able to make educated guesses.  Less precise, but much faster to implement.

Comment: The problem is that I can't sometimes know ahead what is the sync method really doing. It could be developed by somebody, even Microsoft. And the scheduler might not be stupid but it seems not be smart enough to be able to figure out how to improve the performance on its own from 16K to even 50K request per second. I may expect it to fail sometimes to produce the really highest results without some tuning from my side but the boost in this case is too much.

Comment: If you gonna run tasks-returning methods implemented by third-party components — you should definitely use Task.Run. Otherwise, misbehaving or buggy component (e.g. that only returns you a task in 1 minute, because of Thread.Sleep or because of some CPU-bound work) will prevent your HTTP server from serving more requests, which is likely not the behavior you want.

Comment: In my previous comment I meant async instead of sync: "The problem is that I can't sometimes know ahead what is the Async method really doing. It could be developed by somebody". Additionally I mean, I can write a properly formed async method as well as somebody else can, doesn't matter Microsoft or some 3rd party. Still I can not be certain ahead how to call this method, directly or wrap it inside Task.Run. I thought the scheduler is smart enough to arrange everything in such a way that the performance would be the best.

Comment: That whole async-await stuff is a thin abstraction over some callback-based mechanism (different in different tasks). Neither compiler nor scheduler is able to know in advance how long does it take to start a task. If long, then call to an async method will hang the caller thread. This is by design. If you ain’t sure, you have to call Task.Run, or your HTTP listener will stall.